# More elegant way of accessing hashed arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

Firstly, appologies if i get any terminology wrong on the upcoming post, this is all still very new to me.

Some background, I have a script that checks our archived network configs for a specific set of settings. As such, the script runs a number of checks, and adds the results to an  array for that check.

e.g 
a check to make sure syslog is configured is added to an array called @internalsyslogerror

after all the checks have run, the arrays for all the checks are added to a hash, with the key being the device name.

note all code has use strict, use warnings

with the following command;

```
$results{$configs} = [@internalsyslogerror, @bordersyslogerror, 
@borderntperror, @borderntperror, @internalntperror, 
@bordertacacserror, @internaltacacserror, @enablepasswordchecks,
@internalsnmpkeyserror, @timezoneerror, @configregistererror, 
@bannererror, @bootregistererror, @domainnameerror];
```

The issue im having is what is the most elegant way of extracting this information, i would like to reduce the amount of changes I have to make in order add a new check to the script.
Currently i would have to add the additional array to the above code and then add the dereferencing part to the sub that handles that.

Here is currently what i do to de-reference and out put to an array which i then send via an email.

```
foreach my $k (keys %results) {
    push @results, "<b>$k</b><br>";
    if (defined $results{$k}[0] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[0]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[1] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[1]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[2] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[2]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[3] ){  
    push @results, "$results{$k}[3]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[4] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[4]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[5] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[5]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[6] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[6]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[7] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[7]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[8] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[8]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[9] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[9]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[10] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[10]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[11] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[11]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[12] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[12]";
    }
    if (defined $results{$k}[13] ){
    push @results, "$results{$k}[13]";
    }
}
```

The question is, can i do what im doing above, but somehow generate the code "on the fly"

Thanks

Comment: Upon glancing at the huge numbers of ifs, I nearly thought I was reading thedailywtf.com :-)

Comment: @denis hence the cry for help :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen enough of your code to be certain that this snippet doesn't alter existing behavior.  But it should be ok.  And it definitely improves maintainability:

```
foreach my $k (keys %results) {
    push @results, "<b>$k</b><br>";
    foreach my $index ( 0..$#{$results{$k}} ) {
        if (defined $results{$k}[$index] ){
            push @results, "$results{$k}[$index]";
        }
    }
}
```

The above replaces your entire foreach / if construct.

Comment: this works amazingly, thank you. I was trying to do this myself, as i knew there was a way of getting the number of arrays, but couldnt quite get it to work. thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach my $k (keys %results) { 
   push @results, "<b>$k</b><br>"; 
   for my $result (@{$results{$k}) {
       next if (!defined $result);
       push @results, $result;
   }
}
```

or even

```
foreach my $k (keys %results) { 
   push @results, "<b>$k</b><br>"; 
   push @results, grep { defined $_ } @{$results{$k}};
}
```

edit: fixed a typo in the last push...

Comment: I like both of these solutions.  After I posted mine I thought, "Why am I dealing with indices?"  But it got accepted so fast I didn't want to make a change.  Good job.

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like this code is.... dysfunctional. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
$results{$configs} = [@internalsyslogerror, @bordersyslogerror, ... ];
```

This would only create one long array of *scalar values*, not an array of *arrays*. Consider this:

```
C:\perl>perl -we "@a=qw(1 2 3 a); @g=(11,22,33,44); $b{key}=[@a,@g]; print qq(@{$b{key}},\n); print qq($b{key}[0]);"
1 2 3 a 11 22 33 44,
1
```

This clearly demonstrates that `$b{key}` contains all the values of both `@a` and `@g`, and that `$b{key}[0]` just refers to the first value in the first array, i.e. `$a[0]`.

In order to do what you seem to be doing, which is to gather the logs into separate variables, under a certain key, you'd have to use array references:

```
$results{$config} = [\@internalsyslogerror, \@bordersyslogerror, ...];
```

The only way I can see your current solution working, is if you have a bug/feature (intended or unintended) earlier in your code whereby the first value in each array contains all the data relevant to that category, e.g.:

`$internalsyslogerror[0] = "device A not responding, shutting down.\ndevice A rebooted.\nyada yada\n ....";`

If this is the case, then what you are doing is equivalent to:

```
$results{$config} = [ $internalsyslogerror[0], $bordersyslogerror[0], ...];
```

**But** if you should ever get two values in one of the arrays, then your system will be screwed up, and you will have a off-by-one error at the end of your report. Unless you use a dynamic for loop to `push` the values, but it will still be messy.

Also, by excluding undefined values, your internal structure - which depends only on order - will be screwed up, so that you will not know if the first value in `@results` comes from `@internalsyslogerror` or `@bordersyslogerror`.

**Conclusion:**

If you are happy with your current system working well, simply use a for loop as suggested by others. Use a dynamic value instead of absolute. I like FMc's solution (slightly altered):

```
# Solution by FMc
for my $k (keys %results) {
    push @results, "<b>$k</b><br>";
    push @results, grep { defined $results{$k}[$_] } 0 .. $#results{$k};
}
```

If, however, you want to preserve the internal structure, you can't exclude undefined values, and you can't join all the different arrays into one, unless the data is already join in strings in the first array value. So:

```
$results{$config} = [ \@array1, \@array2, ...];

....

for my $key (keys %results) {
    push @results, "<b>$key</b><br>";
    my $i=0;
    for my $ref (@{$results{$key}]) {
        push @results, "Array $i:\n<br>" . (defined @$ref ? "@$ref" : "");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The formatting of the output can be finetuned also. Instead of a string join, e.g. `"@array"`, you can do an explicit join: `join("<br>\n", @array)`.

Comment: thanks for the comments, you are correct, in a way, but as with most of my code, its all a little hacky.... After each array is fed into a hash with the device name as the key, the array is then cleared and the next device populates a new array... its something im looking to clear up on the next version. thanks

Comment: @Steve If you use the arrays within a restricted lexical scope, their address will be recreated each loop (so you don't have to clear them manually), and it will be possible to add a reference without corrupting your data. E.g. `for $key (@yada) { my @array = something($key); my @array2 = something2($key); $hash{$key} = [\@array, \@array2]; }` will work just fine.

Comment: ah, thats just what im looking for.. ill test that out thanks

Comment: @Steve You're welcome. In general, I try to always use as few variables as possible, and always in as small scope as possible. So if I need to do `my @array = getvalues(); $out{$key} = \@array`, I instead do `$out{$key} = [ getvalues() ]`, which basically removes the need for a "transport" variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing anything with the key, this is equivalent:

```
@results = map { "$_" } grep {; defined } map { @$_ } values %results;
```